# Better way than RMI to invoke remotely JDBC functionalities?

Tags: java, jdbc, rmi, remote-access

I'm developing a Java application that consists of a persistence layer, a middleware in between that exposes JDBC-like functionality, and the application layer. The middleware and the application will always be in different JVMs. Normally, the application would simply import the JDBC driver and perform all necessary JDBC operations (in the same JVM), just like a simple application that makes connection to an SQL database. In my situation, the application should invoke a getConnection() operation from the middleware to retrieve a Connection object and perform all necessary operations remotely, thus communicating with the middleware remotely.

What is the best protocol to implement such a thing? REST/Http-like implementations are unacceptable due to their overheard. The protocol (and its implementation) should be as lightweight as possible (ideally, should be at the level of sockets). I was thinking classic RMI calls, but I'm afraid of the additional overhead that the RMI introduces. Is there a better implementation or a completely different architecture approach? The middleware must always expose this JDBC functionality, so there's no possibility to change it.

Comment: I use VJDBC: http://vjdbc.sourceforge.net/ in production environments.
It exposes a JDBC Driver through RMI and has a good performance.

Comment: RMI should be adequate. The database and the data transmission will be the main overheads. RMI only really adds serialization overhead to that.

Comment: I see that VJDBC is an old project (last release was in 2007) and I'm not sure how this is maintained. I was thinking of using Jgroups to remotely access objects and transmits data between the two layers, however I'm kind of afraid that this will be a performance killer. I tried some tests and it takes too long to even initiate a chaneel between two remote nodes. Anyone with experience using this tool?

Comment: Did find a solution for this?